# convert a string to json object which the object is given

Tags: java, json, gson

my json data is

```
{"first_name": "zhuochen",
   "menu_tree": {
    "child": [
      { "menuCode": "MYCITI"},
      { "menuCode": "MYCITI"},
      {
        "child": [
            { "menuCode": "MYCITI"},
            { "menuCode": "MYCITI"}]
      }]
   }}
```

I want convert it to a class which has two properties String first_name and String menu_tree
I used `gson.fromJson(str, class);`
but it seems gson will recognize the menu_tree as a object so it can't run successfully

Comment: *"...but it seems gson will recognize the menu_tree as a object..."* What's what it is. If you want it to be a string, change the JSON so it's a string. That said, it seems like it's much more useful as an object than as a string.

Comment: I can't change the json or the target class

Comment: @IgorIvancha: No, not remotely.

Comment: @zhuochenshen: *"I can't change the json or the target class"* Huh? You're pretty much stuck then, if you can't change *either* of those.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest library org.json : [JavaDoc URL](http://www.json.org/java/), [jar file Download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.jar)

[Example]

```
Object obj = "{'a' : '1', 'b' : '2', 'c' : '3'}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj);
```

Comment: it also fail with exception :Expected a ',' or '}'

Comment: @zhuochenshen sorry. JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj.toString());